# Process logfiles progressively: Extract data and send to another process (zabbix)

Tags: python, bash, logging, zabbix

I want to be able to extract data from a number of logfiles. The extracted data would then be sent to zabbix.

To give an example, say that a (huge) logfile contains information like

```
date: processed 566766 lines
date: processed 324523 lines
date: processed 546747 lines
date: processed 005643 lines
```

I want to be able to send this data to Zabbix.

Using awk I would simply do something like

```
cat logfile | awk '/processed \d+ lines/ { system("zabbix command " $3) }'
```

My problem is that because the files are big, and because I don't want duplicated data, I need to find a way to start reading the log file from where if was left off the previous run

So it needs to remember the point it read until the previous time, and start off processing only newly added rows.

I tried **fetchlog** but for some reason it does not work and it has not been maintained.

Do you know a good utility that can keep track of growing log files, or a Pythonic approach to it?

I seem to remember syslog-ng or rsyslog had something for this, but I think they are only for syslog-style logs, while mine are not following any standard.

Regards

Alessandro

Comment: Have you considered logrotate to rotate the logs daily? How often do you plan to send the data to the monitoring system?

Comment: Every few minutes. Rotation unfortunately is not an option.

Comment: so the data of interest 'date: processed 566766 lines' is scattered around the file? In any case, given all your limitations, I think you have to plan to just parse the file once, as it is created, and then send the data of interest to a process that can send it to zabbix per your schedule.  Read up here and other places about mkfifo,.it might help. But you still have the problem that someday, that log file will get too big for the OS and have to be zeroed out and restarted. Then you have to get a fresh handle to the new logfile. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix 2.0 has improved log file monitoring, see [here](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent#supported_item_keys).

format:

```
log[file,<regexp>,<encoding>,<maxlines>,<mode>]
```

For the regexp, you can specify a word that is in every line of your log file.

For mode, **skip** tells Zabbix not to process older data.

example:

```
log[logfile,processed,,,skip]
```

You can script this as well, just store the last line number of each script run in a file, and store it as a variable in your script. Then do something like this:

```
tail -n +$line_number logfile | awk '{print $3}'
```

You can get the last line number with wc:

```
wc -1 logfile > /tmp/number_file
```

You'll need to +1 that so you don't parse the last line twice.

Probably worthwhile to store all the values in a file, prepend the hostname and item key to each line, and use [zabbix_sender](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manpages/zabbix_sender).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi,the log facility in Zabbix does not allow you to extract data from the line you process. It is merely to alert on the content rather than data extraction.

Comment: Thanks for you answer anyway, I am thinking about writing a Python script and seeing how it performs.

Answer (score 0):

The guys at Zabbix seem to have listened to my prayers:

http://blog.zabbix.com/zabbix-2-2-features-part-7-value-extracting-from-logfiles-and-more/2272/#more-2272